# Inserir campo php concatenando data

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir a seguinte combinação, via PHP ou mysql:

Tenho um campo chamado ANO que precisa receber o ANO atual formato 2017, via php ou mysql.

Tenho um campo código que vai precisar receber a concatenação do numero de protocolo + o ano, porém esse protocolo seria o campo ID da tabela que é gerado automaticamente com AI.

Como faria para pegar esse ID, mesmo que não tivesse gerado nenhum campo ainda, pois ele é auto_increment.

Resumindo, ao fazer um novo cadastro, ele pegaria o ID + ano e colocaria dentro do campo CÓDIGO.

Comment: O campo código é auto_incremento?

Comment: Não, apenas o ID é A_I, o código vai receber o ID + ano atual

Comment: Se tem que fazer dois processos! primeiro se insere o registro, pega a Id e dá um update no campo Codigo com ano e id! se tem algum código que possamos se basear?

Comment: eu usava um random para gerar esse código, mas fica muito aleatório,  public function gera_codigo(){
  return substr(time().rand(10000,99999),-15);
 }

Comment: O campo código é varchar na base?

Comment: isso, campo codigo é varchar

Comment: então se gerou o id 1 seria 12017 se fosse id 2 seria 22017
assim por diante?

Comment: Isso mesmo, ai quando muda o ano ele fica 12018, pois são duas chaves primárias, ID e ANO, sendo que se muda o ano o ID volta a ser 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples com uma função, na variável **código** será guardado o código que desejas e depois podes inserir o código na base de dados:

**Obs** o id é proveniente da base de dados e como é um codigo suponho que deverá ser único então o **id** que passas na função também terá de ser único.

```
// $id = $mysql['id'] provem da DB

function generateCode($id){

    //pegar ultimo registo
    $ultimoRegisto = $db->executar("SELECT id FROM denuncia ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); 

    //verifica a data do ultimo registo se 
    //for igual a data atual, incrementa se não começa denovo com valor 1
    if($ultimoRegisto->num_rows['ano'] == date('Y')){
        return $id . date('Y');
    }

    return 1 . date('Y');
}
```

Comment: O ano ele pega normalmente 2017, o problema é como eu vou pegar o ID se ele ainda nem foi gerado?

Comment: Tenta obter o id do ultimo registo da base de dados e soma mais um, assim terás o id unico a ser gerado

Comment: Mas e se o último ID foi 3 do ano de 2017 e for inserir o primeiro cadastro de 2018? ele vai retornar o ID 3 e somar 1

Comment: sim ta correto ao somar 1 fica 4 , que será o primeiro registo de 2018, o id tem de ser unico, tal como o codigo

Comment: É que são duas chaves primárias, ID e ANO, justamente para mudar o valor de acordo com o ano e gerar o protocolo. se o ano for sempre igual ele incrementa o ID, ou seja eu posso ter vários ID 1 em anos diferentes.

Comment: Então pegas o ultimo registo e comparas com o ano atual se for igual incrementa se não reseta o ID para 1

Comment: eu fiz assim  public function gera_codigo() {   
     $db = new mysql();
  $codigo = $db->executar("SELECT id FROM denuncia where ano=ano ");    
  return $codigo->num_rows.date('Y');
 }
Como que faço para implementar essa função que você falou no where?

Comment: resposta editada.

Comment: ta quase OK, ele não incrementou o ID aqui, ou seja não está caindo dentro do IF

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela luz que vc deu, fiz a função assim:  public function gera_codigo() {   
     $db = new mysql();

     //pegar ultimo registo
     $ultimoRegisto = $db->executar("SELECT id FROM denuncia where ano=ano "); 

     //verifica a data do ultimo registo se 
     //for igual a data atual, incrementa se não começa denovo com valor 1
   if($ultimoRegisto->num_rows > 0){
         return $ultimoRegisto->num_rows +1 . date('Y');
     }

     return 1 . date('Y');

 }

Comment: Estamos para a ajudar^^, já esta a funcionar ?

Comment: Sim, tudo ok =D

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer direto no MySql, você pode fazer assim. Por exemplo, criei uma tabela simples, contendo apenas ID (auto_increment) e CODIGO (para concatenar). O INSERT ficou assim:

```
INSERT INTO tb_teste (codigo) 
    VALUES (
       CONCAT(
           YEAR(NOW()),"-", (
                SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
                    FROM information_schema.tables
                    WHERE table_name = 'tb_teste'
                    AND table_schema = DATABASE()
                )
        ));
```

Veja o resultado para este exemplo. Fiz 3 insert's:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta você ajustar o CONCAT para o padrão que você quiser.